# Select the corresponding value from array

Tags: python

I have an array with values taken from plc db.

`datalist = [[plc.comm().data(100.1600.7),plc.comm().data(100.1618.8)],[plc.comm().data(100.1670.7),plc.comm().data(100.1688.8]]` ... And so on.

If my user selects the data of plc address (100.1600.7), I want my UI to display the data stored in (100.1618.8) to my user.

Comment: Why not use a hashmap (Python dictionary)?

Comment: `hashmap[plc_address] = datalist[index of the plc_address]`

Comment: Sorry, but i do not have idea about hashmap dictionary, how exactly it works?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Do some research. If you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [snippet editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: Since you are getting started, I recommend watching the free tutorial series by [Corey Schafer](https://youtu.be/daefaLgNkw0)